# Drag one image at a time to the top of another image

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have 4 images at the bottom of my screen (but in the future I can have more) and 1 image at the top.

I would like to click on the bottom images one at a time and drag to the top image and at the end save the image from above with all the images.

Note: The user can drag one, two or no image so it depends on it.

I have an example below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUSgp.jpg)

[image]

Any tips on how I can do this?

Any API?

Or a Framework?

Any examples in git?

Comment: I guess skiasharp would help you but you will have to write the logic yourself and probably you will need mr.gestures !!

Comment: Removed greetings and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download this [example](https://github.com/mikexxma/DragableView_Demo) and change it to meet your requirement.

I just tested and it works perfectly on Android emulator.

Here is a gif:

[image: Drag image]

Refer: [xamarin-imageview-drag-sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42489687/xamarin-imageview-drag-sample)

Comment: Many thanks for the example, it's a great example for what I want to do.
Stay with God!

Comment: @RodrigoMarques Can you please mark and upvote the answer if it is helpful to you?

Comment: I checked, but the following message appeared:
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.
Thanks again for the dedication.
Stay with God!

Comment: @RodrigoMarques No problem.