# Drag and Drop labels in Xamarin Forms App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, drag-and-drop, label

I have to develop a cross platform app in Xamarin forms and its one of the requirements is to be able to drag and drop dynamically generated labels between different views on same UI (i.e. check the image).[image: Desired drag and Drop functionality]. I have generated the dynamic labels but I am not sure how to implement drag and drop functionality. Can anyone guide me regarding the best choice of controls here like the containers containing the labels? Also do I need to write separate code for implementing the drag and drop on Android and IoS? I will really appreciate if some one can point out the right resource. I have googled but there is not any useful tutorial. Some of the tutorials like this [ListView DragDropSort](https://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2018/03/17/re-order-listview-items-with-drag-drop-ii/) are suggesting writing separate code for Android and IoS platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give you several suggestions:

1. You can use [Mr.gestures](https://www.mrgestures.com/#Documentation) to achieve DragAndDrop in xamarin.forms.

   Check the sample here: [GestureSample](https://github.com/MichaelRumpler/GestureSample), it can easily drag controls, you can also check the discussion in [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/127352/drag-drop-support-in-xamarin-forms).
2. Take a look at [this blog](http://www.xamboy.com/2017/08/23/draggable-view-in-xamarin-forms/), use a `Draggable view in Xamarin Forms`.

   Sample here: [DragViewSample](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/DragViewSample)
3. Here is an android native implementation example of dragging images: [drag-one-image-at-a-time-to-the-top-of-another-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165525/drag-one-image-at-a-time-to-the-top-of-another-image/55178207#55178207)

   Sample here :[DragableView_Demo](https://github.com/mikexxma/DragableView_Demo)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions I also come across two of them already i.e. Mr.Gestures and Draggable view in Xamarin Forms (http://www.xamboy.com/2017/08/23/draggable-view-in-xamarin-forms/). For Mr.Gestures I was concerned as it needs a license key and as far as I understand I have to buy it. Please correct me if I am wrong. Additionally, I have also implemented this Draggable view (http://www.xamboy.com/2017/08/23/draggable-view-in-xamarin-forms/) but for some reasons it is not working and the app is crashing and no touch event (drag and drop) is working.

Comment: Yes, you are right, you have to pay for Mr.Gestures.

Comment: Can you tell me which type of layout I should use for above UI on left where there are several empty boxes/labels in Arrange box in different rows? The layout should allow labels from three boxes on right to be dragged and dropped without being deleted from its layout. For instance, If a user drag "Vet" from top box and drop it in first empty space. It must be dropped but also remains in the first box. I am thinking to use Grid Layout but not sure if it will work.

Comment: Actually, I don't do it before. I can't give you much information about which layout to use and I think it is an complex layout. I will update you if I find anything about it.

Comment: It is quite complex thats why I am seeking help around.